# How to link GOPATH to LiteIDE?

Tags: go, liteide

I've installed LiteIde and exported `GOROOT` and `GOPATH` in my `.bashrc`. When I use LiteIDE, the auto-completion works just fine, but it can't build/run my code. When I look at 'Manage GOPATH', the System GOPATH box is empty, and I can't type into it either.

Looking up online, the solution seems to be - 'link' the `GOPATH` and LiteIDE. How do I 'link' the two?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Select the correct environment for you system from the drop-down:

[image]

For example, if you're on a Mac and used the package installer it would be "darwin64-local" on a 64 bit Mac.

Then click on the "Go" folder icon on the left of the drop-down.

[image]

Click "Add Directory..." and add a folder path that contains `src`, `pkg`, and `bin` folders. Essentially what you set `GOPATH` to.

Make sure you **do not** set GOROOT in `.bashrc` at all. [You don't need to set GOROOT, really](http://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/14/you-dont-need-to-set-goroot-really).

Comment: I followed the instructions, also removed GOROOT from bashrc. But I still get the error: Could not parse action 'Build'

Comment: @tldr OS? Version of LiteIDE?

Comment: Have you tried [X19](https://code.google.com/p/golangide/downloads/detail?name=liteidex19.macosx.zip)?

Comment: That helped a bit, but not entirely. Now I get:

Comment: go build  [/Users/jashua/Desktop/go/src] \n
Error: process failed to start.

Comment: @tldr It would seem that you don't have the correct environment selected. If you installed the package, you should use the "-local" version. If you built it yourself you may have to edit it yourself. Click the icon on the right side of the drop-down to edit it. You should see where LiteIDE is looking for the `go` tool.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much! But now it tries to build everything inside the src directory. If I want to run a simple helloworld program, I can do "go run helloworld.go" in the terminal, and it runs fine. But if I try to build the file in LiteIde, it tries to build all the files in src. Is there anyway to build and run just the file I'm viewing?

Comment: @tldr I'm not sure. I prefer GoSublime personally. You could try right-clicking on the filename, or the build drop-down menu.

Answer (score 4):

Follow the answer above, but then regarding the updated problems with the build path being incorrect:

If you "build" in Liteide then the executable gets put in the same file as your .go file.

But by clicking "install" in Liteide then the executable gets placed in the go workspace root bin folder as it should be.

You can still "run" the code from within Liteide if there is not the executable in the same folder as your .go file.