# liteide setting GOROOT to GOPATH when run

Tags: go, liteide

In the middle of a development session, this stupid behavior started and now it looks permanent.  I have no idea what happened:

```
[dtrombley@sleet bin]$ echo $GOROOT
/usr/lib/golang
[dtrombley@sleet bin]$ echo $GOPATH
/home/dtrombley/go/
[dtrombley@sleet bin]$ ./liteide
```

liteide build error:

```
 ../../github.com/Sirupsen/logrus/writer.go:4:2: cannot find package "bufio" in any of:
/home/dtrombley/go/src/bufio (from $GOROOT)
/home/dtrombley/go/src/bufio (from $GOPATH)
```

What?   Why is it using GOPATH in place of GOROOT?  This used to work, and mysteriously switched to broken *while liteide was running*, from one build to the next, literally a few seconds later...

Has anyone seen this?  Is there some way I can inspect/set the GOROOT within liteide?

[Edit]   Further weirdness:  I thought the / at the end of GOPATH might be confusing it, so I removed that.  Now:

```
 [dtrombley@sleet bin]$ echo $GOROOT
 /usr/lib/golang
 [dtrombley@sleet bin]$ echo $GOPATH
 /home/dtrombley/go
 [dtrombley@sleet bin]$ ./liteide
```

...

```
warning: GOPATH set to GOROOT (/home/dtrombley/go) has no effect
../../github.com/Sirupsen/logrus/writer.go:4:2: cannot find package "bufio" in any of:
/home/dtrombley/go/src/bufio (from $GOROOT)
($GOPATH not set)
```

Misery.

Comment: Slashes on the end of both paths revert to the first quoted error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if GOROOT is set at all in `/usr/share/liteide/liteenv/linux*.env` (which can be an [issue as reported in here](https://github.com/visualfc/liteide/issues/201))
You can also check if [GOROOT is set in other place as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18166659/6309).

Finally check if the issue persists with the [latest liteide (x27.2.1)](https://github.com/visualfc/liteide/releases).

---

The [OP BadZen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/675723/badzen) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30117155/liteide-setting-goroot-to-gopath-when-run/30117889#comment48346900_30117889):

> It switched in the middle of the session because I must have stray clicked and switched my target from `linux64` to `linux32` - the `linux32.env` had the buggy `GOROOT` entry (`GOROOT=$HOME/go`).

Comment: Ah, yeah, that was the problem.   It switched in the middle of the session because I must have stray clicked and switched my target from linux64 to linux32 - the linux32.env had the buggy GOROOT entry (GOROOT=$HOME/go).  Ugh, that should not override environment.  TYVM

Comment: @BadZen Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.